# Google Sheets - Having trouble with FILTER

Tags: google-sheets

I have numeric values in column D, and text data in column H.

I want to return a list of all the D values, whenever "Word" appears in the corresponding row in column H.

I've tried:

`=FILTER(D3:D,H3:H="Word")`

Unfortunately not working, where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to know this without seeing your sheet, layout, data, data types, etc. If you'd like, share a link. The only thing I can suggest site-unseen is that you may be in a locale where semicolons are used in place of commas; so you can try replacing the comma with a semicolon and see if that works.

Comment: Your formula should work. See here: See here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eR_Vtq62IgvaIj3jwsIuzR7bBeXMT3vFAADYsstGJZI/edit#gid=0

Comment: @pgSystemTester

How can it be adjusted so that it returns all results where "word" appears anywhere in the cell? For example if "abcWORDxyz" was in the cell, it would still return it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Player's answer was basically the same as the question (as far as I could tell), I'll challenge the solution with this. Use this formula to evaluate if it contains WORD:

```
=filter(D3:D,ISNUMBER(find("WORD",UPPER(H3:H))))
```

[See sample here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eR_Vtq62IgvaIj3jwsIuzR7bBeXMT3vFAADYsstGJZI/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(D3:D; H3:H="Word")
```

### update:

```
=FILTER(D3:D; REGEXMATCH(H3:H; "(?i)Word"))
```

Comment: Getting the following Error:
No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

Comment: @Dan808 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: How can it be adjusted so that it returns all results where "word" appears anywhere in the cell? For example if "abcWORDxyz" was in the cell, it would still return it. Thanks

Comment: @Dan808 use: `=FILTER(D3:D; REGEXMATCH(H3:H; "(?i)Word"))` answer updated